# hidden in Angular2 don't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I read that better than [hidden] use *ngIf but in my case I don't want remove element from the DOM. 
In component.html i have

```
<article #articleId id="bodyArticle" [hidden]="isClicked"></article>
```

in .ts file

```
isClicked = false;
```

and css

```
article {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

[hidden]{display:none!important}
```

How to fix that and make that article will be invisible ?

edit

Now it's working but now when i try use

```
var myArticle = document.querySelector('article');
myArticle.textContent = this.imageService.getBodyRes();
```

I have error that undefined Why is this happening if article is don't remove from DOM ?

Comment: You could use ngClass to conditionally apply that class when the condition is true.

Comment: If you set `isClicked` to `true`, it will be hidden;

Comment: Set `isClicked` to true. You set it to `false`, and `hidden=false` means `shown=true`.

Comment: Also check http://angularjs.blogspot.ru/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html. Header "Angular 2 [hidden] example (not recommended)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really is nothing wrong with using the `hidden` attribute, but if you would still like to avoid it, you could simply assign a class to the element instead.

```
<article #articleId id="bodyArticle" [class.hidden]="isClicked"></article>
```

Change the CSS accordingly:

```
article.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It's fine because now i try use this articlle  var myArticle = document.querySelector('article'); and i have error that undefined

Comment: why would you want to do it with a css class when angular already provides `[hidden]` and `*ngIf`? any good reason?

Comment: @Faisal To be fair, there is nothing wrong with the native `hidden` attribute, and I have recently added that to my answer. I didn't use `*ngIf` because the original poster specifically stated that they don't want the element to be removed from the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to use `[hidden]` you can do something like:

CSS:

```
.hidden { 
  visibility: none
}
```

then in your HTML:

```
<article #articleId id="bodyArticle" [class.hidden]="isClicked"></article>
```

Comment: It's work fine but now i have error that article is undefined

Comment: I think you are messing "article" with "articleId" or "bodyArticle". There are other ways of getting html tag in TS code than old plain JS `document.get...` and they might be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that through a css class. You can use the `[hidden]` property to show or hide the element.

The mistake you are doing is that `[hidden]` will have an affect when condition is true. You in your case you just need to invert your `isClicked` variable.

```
<article #articleId id="bodyArticle" [hidden]="!isClicked"></article>
```

Also, remove the following from your css:

```
[hidden]{display:none!important}
```

Comment: I firstly i use ngif but i set value to false element is remove from DOM I thinking that when i use [hidden] i should use this article but also have that element is undefined